# Creating a tutorial for my iOS app with page control

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a tutorial for my application with `Page Control`. I'm not entirely sure how to go about creating this tutorial view, and was hoping somebody could provide some advice or point me to a tutorial. I've been researching for several days now but haven't come across any relevant solutions...

I'm essentially wondering what `UI Elements` this uses? A `page control` + `UINagivationController` or `UIViewController`?

[image]

Comment: Page control + scroll view with pagination + some buttons at the bottom. Check out Apple's [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) sample.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a step by step tutorial for what you want to do:
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

The above tutorial shows how to create a UIPageViewController using Interface Builder. The tutorial was rewritten to make it compatible with iOS 7 and Xcode 5 and to use Storyboard. You can find the updated tutorial at this link: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

If you're open to using third party libraries there are several options:

https://github.com/MatthewYork/iPhone-IntroductionTutorial

https://github.com/icepat/ICETutorial

https://github.com/ealeksandrov/EAIntroView

https://github.com/GnosisHub/GHWalkThrough