# Create a guide (tutorial) for my ios app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am creating swift app and I would like to create some tutorial to it(or something that will show how my app works). I have found only this question [Creating a tutorial for my iOS app with page control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215303/creating-a-tutorial-for-my-ios-app-with-page-control) , but it is in objective-c. So my question is: How can I create a tutorial for my ios app , or if you know some page in swift where can I read something about it. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/Athlee/OnboardingKit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this yourself by adding the view(s) and controller(s) as usual and add `NSUserDefaults` to check whether the user is starting the app for the first time or not. If not, you can trigger a segue to your normal Home-ViewController.

Alternatively, you can use one something similar to these:

- https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough
- https://github.com/Athlee/OnboardingKit

Comment: How can I check that user is new with NSUserDefaults? (I am using mysql/php database). Thank you :)

Comment: Set: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(true, forKey: "ifFirstVisit")`. Get: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("ifFirstVisit")`.