# UIPagecontrol and scrolling in swift

Tags: ios

let jsonArray = [["name":"Trend deals","location":"india","description":"welcome","price":"3345","dealstype":"BEST","type":"KITCHEN","imageurl":""],["name":"Best deals","location":"india","description":"welcome","price":"Q78","dealstype":"BEST","type":"KITCHEN1","imageurl":""],["name":"Not Best deals","location":"india","description":"welcome","price":"Q78","dealstype":"BEST","type":"KITCHEN3","imageurl":""]] as Array>

This is my data ,so count is 3.
I need to display the data in a such a way that ....
["name":"Trend deals","location":"india","description":"welcome","price":"3345","dealstype":"BEST","type":"KITCHEN","imageurl":""] should display in the view then scrolling i need to display the second data then scrolling i need to display the 3th data in the view.I need to use pagecontrol also.How to implement.

Comment: Go and read some tutorial  don't ask how to do it.

Comment: did anyone knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement scroll view delegate and page control. Just Google for it.

**Few references:**

[How to create a Scroll View with a page control using swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074454/how-to-create-a-scroll-view-with-a-page-control-using-swift)

https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/changing-screens-with-uipagecontrol

[Creating a tutorial for my iOS app with page control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215303/creating-a-tutorial-for-my-ios-app-with-page-control)

Comment: i know .....and i got the uipageviewcontroller but i want to implement in the mvvm method.In that i cannot able to implement